# Speed up scipy ndimage measurements applied on a numpy 3-d

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, vectorization, ndimage

I have multiple large labeled numpy 2d array (10 000x10 000). For each label (connected cells with the same number) I want to calculate multiple measurements based on the values of another numpy 3-d array (mean, std., max, etc.). This is possible with the scipy.ndimage.labeled_comprehension tool if the 3-d numpy is converted to a 2-d. However, as the numbers of labels and the size of the arrays is rather big, the calculations take quite some time. My current code seems redundant as I am now iterating over the same labels for each 3rd dimension of the input image. I am wondering if there are ways to speed-up my code (for example by combining the three scipy.ndimage.labeled_comprehension calculations into a single calculation).

*Using a test dataset of shape (4200,3000,3) and 283047 labels the calculations took 10:34 minutes*

---

**Test data**

```
example_labels=np.array([[1, 1, 3, 3],
   [1, 2, 2, 3],
   [2, 2, 4, 4],
   [5, 5, 5, 4]])

unique_labels=np.unique(example_labels)
value_array=np.arange(48).reshape(4,4,3)
```

**Current code and desired output**

```
def mean_std_measurement(x):
    xmean = x.mean()
    xstd = x.std()
    vals.append([xmean,xstd])

def calculate_measurements(labels, unique_labels, value_arr):
    global vals
    vals=[]
    ndimage.labeled_comprehension(value_array[:,:,0],labels,unique_labels,mean_std_measurement,float,-1)
    val1=np.array(vals)
    vals=[]
    ndimage.labeled_comprehension(value_array[:,:,1],labels,unique_labels,mean_std_measurement,float,-1)
    val2=np.array(vals)
    vals=[]
    ndimage.labeled_comprehension(value_array[:,:,2],labels,unique_labels,mean_std_measurement,float,-1)
    val3=np.array(vals)
    return np.column_stack((unique_labels,val1,val2,val3))

>>> print calculate_measurements(example_labels,unique_labels,value_array)
array([[  1.        ,   5.        ,   5.09901951,   6.        ,
      5.09901951,   7.        ,   5.09901951],
   [  2.        ,  21.        ,   4.74341649,  22.        ,
      4.74341649,  23.        ,   4.74341649],
   [  3.        ,  12.        ,   6.4807407 ,  13.        ,
      6.4807407 ,  14.        ,   6.4807407 ],
   [  4.        ,  36.        ,   6.4807407 ,  37.        ,
      6.4807407 ,  38.        ,   6.4807407 ],
   [  5.        ,  39.        ,   2.44948974,  40.        ,
      2.44948974,  41.        ,   2.44948974]])
```

Comment: This might not have much impact, but you should calculate `np.unique(labels)` just once at the beginning of the function, and reuse the result in all those function calls.

Comment: You're right, I added it in my script!

Comment: There are dedicated, more optimized functions [`scipy.ndimage.minimum`, `.maximum`, `.mean`, `.median`, `.variance`, and `.standard_deviation`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/ndimage.html#measurements). They should give a healthy speedup, if they provide all the stats you need... If you need more stats, maybe turn the image into a Pandas dataframe with 4 columns and do a `groupby` (could be faster, I don't guarantee it).

Comment: With these functions I have to iterate over the arrays six times instead of 3 times. Which makes the calculation slower. I will try to look into the pandas idea.

Comment: Well, yes you make 6 `ndimage.*` function calls instead of 3. But that doesn't necessarily make it slower. *The dedicated functions are more optimized.* In fact, for the test case of shape (4200,3000,3) and 283047 labels it's 13x faster for me.

Comment: That's weird, as on my pc the calculations with these functions take the same time. I tested it once and the calculations took 10:16

Comment: Okay that is weird. Your code only takes 1:31 minute for me, on a basic laptop, while the one with `ndimage.mean` and `.standard_deviation` only takes a couple of seconds. Maybe there's something funny with your dataset? Or are your timings for the 10k x 10k case perhaps. I used as data `values = np.random.randint(256, size=(4200, 3000, 3))` and `labels = np.random.randint(283047, size=(4200, 3000))`. And I'm on scipy 0.16.1 btw.

Comment: Wow that is fast. When I test with your data I get the same results. I guess it has something to do with the data types I use, as I am also using 32 bit and float arrays.  Never thought of that, but some can be converted to 8-bit without loosing too much information. I will try that out.

Answer (score 0):

The list appends in mean_std_measurement is probably forming a bottleneck when dealing with large arrays. `labeled_comprehension` will return an array on its own, so a first step is to just let scipy handle the array construction under the hood.

`labeled_comprehension` can only apply functions that output a single value---I suspect this is why you were using the list construction in the first place---but we can cheat this by having the function output a complex value. Another option would be to use structured datatypes as the output, which would be necessary if we were returning more than 2 values.

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import ndimage
example_labels=np.array([[1, 1, 3, 3],
   [1, 2, 2, 3],
   [2, 2, 4, 4],
   [5, 5, 5, 4]])

unique_labels=np.unique(example_labels)
value_array=np.arange(48).reshape(4,4,3)
# return a complex number to get around labled_comprehension limitations
def mean_std_measurement(x):
    xmean = x.mean()
    xstd = x.std()
    return np.complex(xmean, xstd)

def calculate_measurements(labels, unique_labels, value_array):
    val1 = ndimage.labeled_comprehension(value_array[:,:,0],labels,unique_labels,mean_std_measurement,np.complex,-1)
    val2 = ndimage.labeled_comprehension(value_array[:,:,1],labels,unique_labels,mean_std_measurement,np.complex,-1)
    val3 = ndimage.labeled_comprehension(value_array[:,:,2],labels,unique_labels,mean_std_measurement,np.complex,-1)
    # convert the complex numbers back into reals
    return np.column_stack((np.unique(labels),
                            val1.real,val1.imag,
                            val2.real,val2.imag,
                            val3.real,val3.imag))
```

Comment: *"This actually runs a little slower..."*  What size array did you use when you measured the time?  The OP is interested in arrays of size (10000, 10000).  Timing for an array with size (4, 4) is probably irrelevant.

Comment: Using a test dataset of shape (4200,3000,3) and 283047 labels the calculations took 10:34 minutes. With your approach the time was almost the same 10:12 minutes. Thanks for the effort anyway!

Comment: Bummer. Looking at the source in `scipy/ndimage/measurements.py`, it seems that your original hypothesis (that iterating over the labels thrice was the bottleneck) was right. I'd recommend either rewriting the function to handle differently dimensioned label and data arrays, or monkeying around with structured datatypes. (I tried the second and didn't get so far though).